SONY camera API (start recording via Wifi in VB.NET tool)
For a project, I would like to start recording on my SONY A7Siii camera via a homemade tool in VB.NET
The camera is connected to my network via Wifi.
From the computer I can ping the camera, and also access for example this URL on the camera: http://192.168.1.88:64321/dd.xml
Using ChatGPT, I managed to create the below piece of code. But unfortunately an error message keeps coming up: Error: 192.168.1.88: 34048
Does anyone have an idea how I should handle this?
`Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Public Class Form1
' DLLImports voor de Camera Remote SDK
<DllImport("Cr_Core.dll", EntryPoint:="Connect", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Public Shared Function ConnectCamera(ByVal ipAddress As String, ByRef cameraHandle As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("Cr_Core.dll", EntryPoint:="SendCommand", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Public Shared Function SendCommand(ByVal cameraHandle As IntPtr, ByVal commandId As Integer, ByVal param As Integer) As Integer
End Function

' Command ID's en parameters
Const CrCommandId_MovieRecord As Integer = &H1002
Const CrCommandParam_Start As Integer = 1
Const CrCommandParam_Stop As Integer = 2

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Try

        Dim cameraIp As String = "192.168.1.88"
        Dim cameraHandle As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

        Dim connectResult As Integer = ConnectCamera(cameraIp, cameraHandle)
        If connectResult <> 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {cameraIp}: {connectResult}")
            Return
        End If
        Console.WriteLine("Connected with camera.")

        Dim startResult As Integer = SendCommand(cameraHandle, CrCommandId_MovieRecord, CrCommandParam_Start)
        If startResult <> 0 Then
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {startResult}")
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Recording started.")
        End If


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Error: " & ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub

End Class
`
I have been searching on Google all day yesterday and have been using ChatGPT a lot. I also searched this forum, but it doesn't seem like this has been covered much yet.
